# Pandas: tricky interval selection based on varying ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm relatively new to coding and have a tricky (to me) logic determination sequence that I assume can be simplified from what I currently have. I have yet to be able to find something similar that I can comprehend at my current level of understanding and thus adapt accordingly.

I have a data frame containing a list of ~200 wells. Each well has a different depth of a perforated casing that exposes it to groundwater at various depths (open interval). The length/depth of the open interval ranges for each well. Based on the open interval, I need to determine which layers within a groundwater model should be associated to each individual well (location within the model is given by row/column values) and then append that information to an array for export in text format that will be fed back into the model (I've got that part). Furthermore, the number of layers could potentially increase, so ideally the code could adapt to any number of layers. I would always have some form of the example data set below. If the layers increase, the data set with those new values would be provided by the model. The well open interval will not change, and thus which layers each well's open interval exist within would change.

Example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'well_ID': ['GR800', 'HA009', 'HA219', 'HA323','HA463'],
                  'Top_open_int':[4450.0, 4530.0, 4390.0, 3900.0, 4140.0], #top of open interval
                  'Bot_open_int':[4110.0, 3800.0, 4250.0, 3750.0, 3650.0], #bottom of open interval
                  'Top_1':[4500.0, 4550.0, 4100.0, 4200.0, 4150.0], #top of layer 1
                  'Bot_1':[4300.0, 4250.0, 3900.0, 4050.0, 3900.0], #bottom of layer 1
                  'Bot_2':[4100.0, 3900.0, 3750.0, 3850.0, 3750.0], #bottom of layer 2
                  'Bot_3':[3820.0, 3650.0, 3520.0, 3650.0, 3570.0], #bottom of layer 3
                  'Bot_4':[3360.0, 3480.0, 3300.0, 3380.0, 3350.0]}) #bottom  of layer 4
```

What I'm currently doing is something like below, where I'm writing up every possible boundary condition combination that could exist. If the number of layers increase, I have to add all the additional possible combinations to the script.

Current script approach:

```
# initiate empty array
layers = []

# loop through all combinations and appending appropriate text if the interval matches
for well, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Top_open_int'] >= row['Bot_1'] and row['Bot_open_int'] < row['Bot_3']:
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '1', row['Row'], row['Column']))
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '2', row['Row'], row['Column']))
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '3', row['Row'], row['Column']))
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '4', row['Row'], row['Column']))

    elif row['Top_open_int'] >= row['Bot_1'] and row['Bot_open_int'] < row['Bot_2']:
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '1', row['Row'], row['Column']))
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '2', row['Row'], row['Column']))
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '3', row['Row'], row['Column']))

    elif row['Top_open_int'] >= row['Bot_1'] and row['Bot_open_int'] < row['Bot_1']:
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '1', row['Row'], row['Column']))
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '2', row['Row'], row['Column']))

    elif row['Top_open_int'] > row['Bot_1'] and row['Bot_open_int'] >= row['Bot_1']:
        layers.append((row['well_ID'], '1', row['Row'], row['Column']))

     # script continues for all possible combinations that the open interval could 
     # potentially fall within. There doesn't seem to be a point in writing it all out here
```

If you run the above code you'll see what the expected outcome would be. It would be an array like this, but for all the wells in the data set:

```
[('GR800', '1', 20, 100),
 ('GR800', '2', 20, 100),
 ('HA009', '1', 45, 10),
 ('HA009', '2', 45, 10),
 ('HA009', '3', 45, 10),
 ('HA219', '1', 105, 65),
 ('HA463', '1', 250, 15),
 ('HA463', '2', 250, 15),
 ('HA463', '3', 250, 15)]
```

Is there a way to simplify this approach and make it more robust so that it can adapt to changes in the number of layers?

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: @Allen - See edited question. I just need a simply array that has the ID, layer, row, column for each well. If a well's open interval is open to 3 layers, it would have 3 lines like the bottom 3 of the output. However, the code I pasted is not complete so it's not showing all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but these 3 lines will do the work of that for loop:

```
df[(df['Top_open_int'] >= df['Bot_1']) & (df['Bot_open_int'] >= df['Bot_3'])]
df[(df['Top_open_int'] >= df['Bot_1']) & (df['Bot_open_int'] >= df['Bot_2'])]
df[(df['Top_open_int'] >= df['Bot_1']) & (df['Bot_open_int'] >= df['Bot_1'])]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code does not seem to do what I need to have done. Thank you for your input though.